# Files are missing when try to open my react native project in Xcode to build IPA

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I am building project with react native and its completed. I have also generated APK file successfully, however when I tried to open project in Xcode it showing many files as missing mainly are libraries and font files.

I had used below URL to generate ios build
https://medium.com/@tunvirrahmantusher/create-ipa-and-apk-from-react-native-72fe53c6a8db

not sure what is wrong and why files are missing, any suggestion or help will really helpful.

Thank you in advance.

I have tried to build iOS folder twice but its not working either

If someone can say why those files are missing an what can be done to get those files in xCode and I can run project in xCode also that will really help.

Comment: Have you tried linking the libraries again using **react-native link** ?

Comment: Also: fonts and libraries can easily be added in Xcode in Build Phases (Link Binary With Libraries and Copy Bundle Resources)

Comment: @dentemm yes I did use react-native link, but its still showing library files are missing. what can be the possible issue? or any mistake I am doing from my side while generating iOS build?

Comment: Issue got resolved now. App is working fine on xcode